# Why isn't QuickActionDefaultsHandler working in Spring '17?

Tags: apex, quickaction

The following code is working for me in Winter '17 but not Spring '17:

```
global class EmailPublisherLoader implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler {
// Empty constructor
global EmailPublisherLoader() {
}

// The main interface method
global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {
    QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults sendEmailDefaults = null;

    // Check if the quick action is the standard Case Feed send email action
    for (Integer j = 0; j < defaults.size(); j++) {
        if (defaults.get(j) instanceof QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults && 
            defaults.get(j).getTargetSObject().getSObjectType() == EmailMessage.sObjectType && 
            defaults.get(j).getActionName().equals('Case.Email') && defaults.get(j).getActionType().equals('Email')) {
               sendEmailDefaults = (QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)defaults.get(j);
               break;
        }
    }

    if (sendEmailDefaults != null) {

        EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)sendEmailDefaults.getTargetSObject();
            emailMessage.BccAddress = null;
      }     
    }
}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  Or is the action failing silently?

Comment: It's failing silently.

Comment: Have you inserted debug statements to identify which piece is failing?

Comment: Debug statements are failing silently, too.

Comment: If that's the case it sounds like you're never entering this code block at all - could it be a config issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you, @SFDC Neuf! This was the problem:

[image]

Comment: I'm curious, was this related to the upgrade to Spring '17?

Comment: Nope, I just forgot that I hadn't configured or tested this functionality in this sandbox before.